# Why I cannot type continuously in react Input field when passing values to another component using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass values through `props` from one component to another.
Parent component is `InstructorLoginForm` and child component is `InstructorLoginFormComponent`

Everything works fine but the problem is I cannot type in input text field **continuously**

I try to type `username`, it types one letter and then it kind loses the focus into the input field, so **I have to again click on the input field and type another(single) letter and again focus loses**
This is same for the `password` field too.

Hers is my parent component `InstructorLoginForm.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import InstructorProfile from "./instructor-profile";
import InstructorLoginFormComponent from "./instructor-login-form-component";

export default class InstructorLoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleOnClick (){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(`/instructor/${this.state.username}`);    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            component={props => (
              <InstructorLoginFormComponent
                {...props}
                username = {this.state.username}
                password = {this.state.password}
                handleOnClick = {this.handleOnClick}
                onChangeUsername = {this.onChangeUsername}
                onChangePassword = {this.onChangePassword}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path={"/instructor/:instructorId"}
            component={InstructorProfile}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my child component `InstructorLoginFormComponent.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class InstructorLoginFormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container h-100" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
          <div className="user_card bg-dark">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">              
            </div>
            <div
              className="d-flex justify-content-center form_container"
              style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
            >
              <form>
                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-user" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={this.props.username}
                    onChange={this.props.onChangeUsername}
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="username"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="input-group mb-2">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-lock" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={this.props.password}
                    onChange={this.props.onChangePassword}
                    type="password"
                    name="passwordbutton"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="password"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="custom-control-input"
                      id="customControlInline"
                    />
                    <label
                      className="custom-control-label"
                      htmlFor="customControlInline"
                      style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
                    >
                      Remember me
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
              <button
                // to={`/instructor/${this.props.username}`}
                onClick={this.props.handleOnClick}
                type="button"
                className="btn login_btn bg-info"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone help me why this happens and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type text, the state of the parent component updates and render function calls again. You used

```
<Route component={...} />
```

it calls `React.createElement` at every render, so old child component unmounts and router creates new instance, focus loses. 
To fix this issue use

```
<Route render={<InstructorLoginFormComponent ... />} />
```

it also provides {match, location, history} props to child, but does not unmount it when parent state changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put it this way, but this is poor architecture along with a few mistakes in syntax.
You should have all routes in your `App.js` file and everything else in your Component file (should actually be a `Container.js` file and a `Component.js` file, but for another time).
You only need one `onChange` event (note change to the function structure).
The below behaves as it should.
Please note the `handleOnClick` should have (e), that should be throwing an error.
Please note password name in the input has been corrected to password, from password button

App.js;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import InstructorProfile from "./instructor-profile";
import InstructorLoginFormComponent from "./instructor-login-form-component";

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            component={InstructorLoginFormComponent }
          />

          <Route
            path={"/instructor/:instructorId"}
            component={InstructorProfile}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

and InstructorLoginFormComponent;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class InstructorLoginFormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleOnClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.history.push(`/instructor/${this.state.username}`)    
  }
 
  render() {
    const { username, password } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="container h-100" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
          <div className="user_card bg-dark">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">              
            </div>
            <div
              className="d-flex justify-content-center form_container"
              style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
            >
              <form>
                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-user" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={username}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="username"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="input-group mb-2">
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <span className="input-group-text bg-info">
                      <i className="fa fa-lock" />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <input
                    value={password}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    className="form-control input_user"
                    placeholder="password"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="custom-control-input"
                      id="customControlInline"
                    />
                    <label
                      className="custom-control-label"
                      htmlFor="customControlInline"
                      style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
                    >
                      Remember me
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
              <button
                // to={`/instructor/${this.props.username}`}
                onClick={this.props.handleOnClick}
                type="button"
                className="btn login_btn bg-info"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```